# Abelian subgroups of special linear group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, simple-groups

Let $F$ be a locally finite field of prime characteristic $p$ and let $q$ be a prime distinct from $p$.

Is it true that the abelian $q$-subgroups of $SL(2, F)$ have finite rank?
In the affirmative case, how to prove it? or where is a prove of this result?

Comment: Well such a subgroup is diagonalizable by Maschke's Theorem for finite groups so the question is equivalent to asking whether abelian $q$-subgroups of $F^\times$ have finite rank. The same applies to abelian $q$-subgroups of ${\rm SL}(n,F)$ for any $n$.